# Extra files in table section of SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am wonder what are the extra files for and can they be moved?
[image]

Comment: Those aren't "files", those are *tables* (default ones created during installation).

Comment: can I move them. Or can I make a new folder for my tables?

Comment: Which account are you connected to? Hopefully not `SYS` or `SYSTEM`... or at least, hopefully you haven't created your own tables in either of those schemas?

Comment: I followed some instructions on YouTube, I'm in SYSTEM. No tables have been made yet